# Email from Lower Hierarchy User to Upper Hierarchy User(Parent Business Unit) by workflow in MS CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-4

I want to create Workflow for Un-Attended Lead more than 24 hours then Email will shoot Automatically to User as {BM(BranchManager)}

My Business Unit Hierarchy is :

Main Organisation  >>  RBH Trading(Head)  >>  BM Trading(Branch Manager)  >>  RM Trading(Relational Manager)

![enter image description here][1]

So, if any RM will not attend his Lead until 24 hours then 1 Auto Email should send to his BM.

Actually the Problem is how to set BM Email into Email Template's "To" Field and i cannot fix any 1 BM there.

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user has any relationship to the branch manager (via a lookup on the user form) then you can leverage that relationship to select the branch manager from the related entities there.

Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, thank you Nick but in User there is already 2 lookup's of Business Unit and Parent Business Unit ok.

In Business Unit - User self belongs to like - RM (City Name)
and
In Parent Business Unit - User belongs to Branch Unit (Branch Manager)

Comment: And the Problem is - When i am Creating a workflow for email shoot (if Lead is un-attended until 24 hours.) to his Branch Manager.

So, what to set in "To" field of Email Template because there is no option to select Business Unit or Parent business Unit in "To" field and i cannot fix any user of BM Level in "To" field.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: And when i am selecting Branch Name(Business Unit), Created by is selecting by default inside Workflow Email Template.
So its not working :(

PLEASE HELP!